# Solving Linear algebraic equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$P = H^* H'$ and
$H'^* H = I_2$

$P$ is $m \times m$ known matrix.
$I_2$ is $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

$H$ is $m\times 2$ matrix.

How to solve for $H$?

Comment: Please give some more context about where this question came from, what you have tried to solve it (or what you background is so we know how to help).

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
  H = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \\ \dots & \dots \\ x_m & y_m \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  H' = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_m \\ y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_m \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Then, 
$$
  H'\cdot H = \begin{bmatrix}
             \sum_{i=1}^m x_i x_i & \sum_{i=1}^mx_i y_i \\
             \sum_{i=1}^m x_i y_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y_i y_i
             \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
If you think in terms of vectors, where
$$
  \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_m \end{bmatrix}^T
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  \mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_m \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
we can write the above equation as
$$
  H'.H = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x} &  \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} \\
     \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} & \mathbf{y}\cdot\mathbf{y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \,.
$$
That means the length of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is 1, that of $\mathbf{y}$ is 1, and these two vectors are perpendicular to each other.  There can be an infinite number of such vectors.

We have to constrain the set of possible vectors ($\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$) with your first equation:
$$
  P = H\cdot H' = \begin{bmatrix} 
          x_1x_1 + y_1y_1 & x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 &\dots & x_1x_m+y_1y_m \\
          x_2x_1 + y_2y_1 & x_2x_2 + y_2y_2 &\dots & x_2x_m+y_2y_m \\
          \dots & \dots & \ddots & \dots\\
          x_mx_1 + y_my_1 & x_mx_2 + y_my_2 &\dots & x_mx_m+y_my_m
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Take the $j$-th column of matrix $P$, 
$$
  \mathbf{P}_j = x_j\,\mathbf{x} + y_j\,\mathbf{y}
$$
A vector product of this column with $\mathbf{x}$ gives
$$
  \mathbf{P}_j\cdot\mathbf{x} = x_j
$$
Expanded out,
$$
  P_{1j}\,x_1 + P_{2j}\,x_2 + \dots + P_{mj}\,x_m = x_j \,.
$$
So you have an equation that contains only $x_j$ and $P_j$ that can be written out in matrix form as
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} 
     P_{11} & P_{21} & \dots & P_{m1} \\
     P_{12} & P_{22} & \dots & P_{m2} \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     P_{1m} & P_{2m} & \dots & P_{mm}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{bmatrix}  
$$ 
This is an eigenvalue problem with eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$:
$$
 (\mathbf{P}^T - \lambda\mathbf{I})\,\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \,.
$$
If you repeat the process with $\mathbf{y}$, you will see that it is another eigenvector of the matrix $\mathbf{P}^T$.

I think a solution should follow at this stage.